# How to add multiple filters in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to apply volume increase, brightness increase and placing the logo in top right of the video.
Please correct me:

`ffmpeg -y -i input_video_path -i logo_path -filter_complex "[0:1]volume=volume=6dB:precision=fixed;[0:0]eq=gamma=1.5:saturation=1.3;[1:0]overlay= main_w-(overlay_w + 10): 10" -pix_fmt yuvj420p output_video_path`

I am getting this error after apply this:

`Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_overlay_2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide labels for each filter:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input_video_path -i logo_path -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=volume=6dB:precision=fixed[a];[0:v]eq=gamma=1.5:saturation=1.3[bg];[bg][1:0]overlay=main_w-(overlay_w + 10):10,format=yuvj420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output_video_path
```

See [FFmpeg Filtering Introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) for an illustrated example.